# how to create a transaction number that has auto increment but do not start in 1 instead a desire number

Tags: php, mysql, insert

how to create a transaction number that has auto increment but do not start in 1 instead a desire number.

example my table in database has column of id,height, width, total, amount, transaction_number.

all in all 6 column

the id is int and  auto increment and ofcourse starts in 1, the height is varchar, width is varchar, total is varchar and amount is varchar then transaction_number is int.

i want is that when the customer order, the system will create transaction number that start 2015001 for the 1st transaction and will auto increment base of the number of transaction.

so can any one help me how to do that and insert it in database

my database insert code is this:

```
$height = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["height"]);
$width = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["width"]);
$total = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["total"]);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["amount"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_newcustomer (height,width,total,amount,transaction_number) 
    VALUES ('$height','$width','$total','$amount',  )";
```

so how will i put the transaction_number into this statement

what i want is transaction_number starts with 2015001 and will auto increment.

can someone post a code to help me

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?  your tags include both and the commands are different to seed the values.

Comment: maybe you are also looking for a transaction number that is reset every year automatically?

Comment: You have a couple of really bad code smells in here. First of all, why are height, width and total varchars? Your new desired number has an issue because you using it to hide some information. You have the year in there which means you are putting additional information into a value. Last but not least, with your current numbering scheme you limit yourself to 999 transactions in a year.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_newcustomer` AUTO_INCREMENT = 2015001
```

However, the problem is that transaction_number doesn't seem to be the AUTO_INCREMENT field, if it's not, then you will need to increment it from your application (getting the highest transaction_number and setting the current row's transaction_number to the previous counter + 1)

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table and set auto incremented value to your desire value

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1001(value that you want)
```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

> **Syntax for MySQL**
>
> By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.
>
> To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
> ```

However, it has to be done after `CREATE TABLE`.